# /tmp/cache directory problem

Tags: php, iis, caching, directory

I have just started out with testing some php mvc framework

In it, it has this function that throws an error.
The cachedirectory is set to **/tmp/cache** from the config file

additional:
The php is hosted on an **IIS serve**r.

Can someone help me out to get this working somehow?

*This is the function within the class*

```
function setCacheDir($cacheDir = null)
    {
        if( is_null( $cacheDir ) )
        {
            $config = config::getInstance();
            $cacheDir = $config->config_values['template']['cache_dir'];
        }

        if (is_dir($cacheDir) && is_writable($cacheDir))
        {
            $config = config::getInstance();
            $this->cache_dir = $cacheDir;
        }
        else
        {

            throw new Exception("De cache directory '$cacheDir' either does not exist, or is unwriteble");
        }
    }
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: It might be helpful to know what exactly is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the cache directory to something a little more Windows-y, like c:\temp (and make sure that folder exists).

Comment: thanks both, I think that worked
I see a whole lot off other errors, but not this one now

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing "/tmp/cache" doesn't exist and isn't writable, so in the configuration file, set cache_dir to a directory that is.

Answer (score 0):

Some PHP frameworks work best (or better) in a LAMP stack, the first letter (L) being Linux. If the documentation of your framework advises a LAMP stack, I'd go with that.